# Google Adwords API: ReportDefinitionService: How to identify valid "report column" combination?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am working on Google Adwords API v201101. Basically, I need to
generate reports using "ReportDefinitionService".

I need help to identify/validate "report column" combinations. Many
times it gives the error ***invalid combination of columns*** for some report
types, and I need to re-select columns.

So how do I identify the valid column combinations before generating a
report?
Is there any set of rules or reference or list available which shows the
valid column combinations for each report category?

And It would be great if you can suggest the best way to
validate columns before generating a report for avoiding such errors.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out. I am having the similar issues as you. I get the error: ReportDefinitionError.INVALID_FIELD_NAME_FOR_REPORT. ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726491/how-do-i-find-out-which-column-combinations-are-valid-in-adwords

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the getReportFields operation. You send in the report type and get back the available fields.

Please see:
http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/ReportDefinitionService.html